# Ruby on Rails - Social Share Button Gem; Modifying what is filled automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Question: How can I use the social share button gem to auto filled certain social media text areas I want?**

Since there isn't much documentation regarding the social share button gem (https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button), I would like some help in trying to create some custom, auto-filled entries when users click each button, namely for FaceBook and Reddit.

Basically, when I have an item displayed, I want a user to click the appropriate social media button to say something like, "I just bought this item from this website".

This is the code I have:

```
<%= social_share_button_tag('I have bought, '+ @item.name + ' , from The Store: ', :allow_sites => %w(twitter)) %>
```

This code works perfectly for twitter. As it says:

```
I have bought, Book, from The Store: http://localhost:3000/items/57#
```

That was simple enough, but trying to have autofilled areas for Reddit or Facebook is just not working.

This is the FB code I've got:

```
<%= social_share_button_tag('Share to Facebook', :url => item_path(@item), desc:  @donate_item.name, :allow_sites => %w(facebook)) %>
```

And what this code does is puts the url and the title of the item in the link, as shown:

[image: FB Image]

I want to have an auto filled text in the "Say something about this", and I am not sure what to do.

Regarding the Reddit shareable link, I've got this:

```
<%= social_share_button_tag(@item.name, :allow_sites => %w(reddit)) %>
```

And it produces:

[image: RedditImage]

Similar to the FB sharing, I want to be able to automatically fill in the "title" area. I have modified the code such as:

```
<%= social_share_button_tag(@item.name, title: "This item is great!", :allow_sites => %w(reddit)) %>
```

And it doesn't work.

Any help would be great, as I just don't know what to look for in the actual source.

Comment: Haven't used the library so can't provide too much guidance but it looks like this is where the social_share_button_tag helper is defined: https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button/blob/master/lib/social_share_button/helper.rb

Answer (score 1):

Checking the gem itself, I don't think it supports passing titles through to Reddit.

If we look at where `social_share_button_tag` comes from: https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button/blob/master/lib/social_share_button/helper.rb, we can see that it calls `SocialShareButton.share(this);` on click.

In https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button/blob/6d329c9fadddd159e2b78310f8220f7e56a8d701/app/assets/javascripts/social-share-button.coffee, we can then see the actual URL it generates for each different social media platform and when we look for Reddit, we see:

```
# line 95
when "reddit"
        SocialShareButton.openUrl("http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=#{url}&newwindow=1", 555, 400)
```

You'll notice the url param is present but title is not (compared to the other urls where the title IS passed through.

At the same time, looking at Reddit's API: https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/API:-submit submitting a pull request for the gem to support the title params doesn't look like it'd be too much work and might be your best bet.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Oh my bad, changed to a comment. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: Well, it’s up to you, but it sorta violates the guidelines on [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) here since it does not indeed contains _the answer_.

Comment: @MichaelFok you should. Unless you dig into the helper yourself and you'll provide code that will do what has been asked, stick to making a comment.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinKołodziej, I'll go ahead and delete it then

Comment: Decided to go back and actually dive into the gem, found some details that should help OP I think? (In that the library does not  do what OP wants it to do)